# How to route requests to desired endpoint using Environment Variables in APIGEE

Tags: apigee

I've a situation where I need to route requests to desired endpoint based on Environment the request hits. for example QA - QA, Prod to Prod

I've configured a proxy and defined a default target host during initial config.

Then I'm using a javascript to decide target host based on the env the request comes in.

```
var env = context.getVariable('environment.name');  

if(env=="prod") {
     var host = 'https://prod.com';
}
if(env=="test") {
     var host = 'https://qa.com';
}
```

I've used this JS file in target endpoint(default) preflow as a step.

I see that all requests are sent to the default host that I configured during initial process.

Am I missing something here please help.

Also I've seen about using Target Server Env config. I've configured the hosts but how do I reference/use it in my proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I usually set the target endpoint (it is the same to host of yours) in Key Value Mapping of '**Environment Configuration**' of Apigee.

And then assign it to variable (example assign it to variable name `endpointUrl`) in **Key Value Maps Operation policy**

Finally, use it in your Target Request Message like below.

```
<AssignVariable>
     <Name>target.url</Name>
     <Ref>endpointUrl</Ref>
</AssignVariable>
```

Adventage of this method is if your host changed, you just edit the value in Key Value Mapping not edit in your code and do not need to re-deploy your API.

However, I answer you from my work experience only.

Maybe you have try to go Apigee Community, you may found the solution that suits you.